# Program outputting random number in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers

I'm doing a program that asks the user for names and an ID number...Then I have added a search function e.g search for the name "bob" it says "Bob was found in array position x with ID:xxxxx"

My problem is that the "ID:xxxx" portion of the code is giving me random numbers...It should be for e.g 1234 but it's giving me things like 4210832

Here is the code

```
void search_surname()
{
    int index, found=0;
    char surname_to_find[10];

    printf("Please enter the student surname to search for\n\n");
    gets(surname_to_find);
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");
    for(index=0;index<height_of_array;index++)
    {

        if(strcmpi(surname_to_find, surname[index]) == 0)
        {
            found=1;

            system("cls");                                                      
            printf("%s found in array position %i, with the ID: %i \n\n", surname_to_find,     
            index+1, id[array_index] );
            getch();
```

I'm not 100% sure WHY it's giving me random numbers

thanks.

Comment: Did you compile with warnings enabled?

Comment: `gets` should not be used under any circumstances. It opens a buffer overflow hole that **cannot be fixed** except by not using `gets`. Besides that, you really need to indent your code.

Comment: And what's `height_of_array`? Please post all the necessary code.

Comment: okay I'll use something else other than gets, but that's not the problem. 

sorry if the code isn't indented, it is in the program. just not on this.

id[array_index] is the array

Comment: Don't use `gets` and **never** use `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: where is `array_index` assigned?

Comment: Height_of_array is that the number of inputs

Answer (score 1):

change `id[array_index]` to `id[index]`

Answer (score 1):

You've posted code so incomplete that it's not possible to point out the exact answer. So instead, a way to approach the problem:

- First, its weird that you're using `id[array_index]` instead of `id[index]`, as `index` is the variable in your for loop. (`array_index` isn't defined in your function; is it a global? Please avoid globals!).
- Nowhere in your example code is `id` being filled, or even declared. Confirm that it is filled correctly. Using `id` without filling in the values first will print out weird things (its uninitialized). A debugger should make confirming its filled correctly easy. Otherwise, just loop over it and print it out.
- Use a debugger to watch your program run.

One last thing: C has structs. There isn't a reason to use multiple arrays like that.

```
struct surname_info {
    unsigned int id;
    const char *surname;
};
⋮
struct surname_info surnames[10];
surnames[0].id = 1234;
surnames[0].surname = "Bob";
/* etc */
```

Comment: Array_index is a global. the ID was stored from a previous input. now I just want it to output with the corresponding name

Comment: @ChristopherRobbieBarclayKel: When you look for the *name*, you're using `index`, but when you try to print the id, you're using `array_index`. That's two different variables. The index you found is in `index`, why are you looking for the ID in a different position?